# Best Way to extend Interop Word base objects

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I'm developing a **Microsoft Word Addin** and I need to extend properties and/or behaviors of somes Word Base objects, as `Word.Comment`.

For example, from this code in **C#** :

> Word.Comment comment = ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(myRange, myString);

How to extends `Word.Comment` class and make this factory method `Comments.Add()` returns an instance of my extending class of `Word.Comment` ?
Is it possible ? If no , are there other ways another way to add properties to base objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply extend the actual word objects. There are a few ways how you can do it though.

Probably the best way would be to wrap the Word.Comment object in one of your objects. For example:

```
class MyComment{
   private Word.Comment comment;

   // some additional logic  
}
```

Then you would just use this class instead of the Word's comment class. You could do something similar for the method.

There are a few well know patterns that describe this kind of logic: [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). It is often used when dealing with 3rd party APIs.

You can also achieve similar behaviour with [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Extension methods can figure as a good alternative. Word.Comment encapsulation with specified patterns alert me on the recurrent issue concerning Word object model manipulation without properly release COM objects. (read this for example http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/)